# How can I know which of my compilers calls which version of a specific library?

Tags: compiling, c, libraries

I have a library `abc` installed in various places of my computer which versions may differ.

I also have different compilers `comp1` and `comp2`.

By executing the two following commands, I end up with two slightly different executables. `prog1` and `prog2` both run, but some internal values differ.

1. `comp1 -o prog1 my_code.c -labc`
2. `comp2 -o prog2 my_code.c -labc`

I suspect that the linker may call different version of `abc` lib depending on the compiler I use. I would like to know if this is specified somewhere and where it is written what to do when someone calls `-labc` in a command line.

Comment: The _compilers_ don't call your libraries at all. The linker may link your code with a specific version of a library, but it (in general) doesn't run any code from your libraries.

Comment: See `ldd prog2` to get the libraries that are going to be used in runtime.